# Node js + mysql2: Should I check for errors in both connection.on('error', fn1) and connection.connect(fn2), or one of these checks is sufficient?

Tags: node.js, mysql2

My current code is:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
function createConnection() {
return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: "3306",
        user: "root",
        database: "UniversityEmployeesDB",
        password: ""
    });
    connection.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(`Error while creating a MySQL connection: ${err.toString()}`);
        rej(err);
    });
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Error while connecting to MySQL server: ${err.toString()}`);
            rej(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Connection with the MySQL server was successfully established.");
            res(connection);
        }
    });
});
}
```

I tested it on error scenarios, turning off my local MySQL server and setting a wrong access login and/or password, and server console logs show that both onerror event and connection.connect fire on error showing exactly the same result. So I sespected that it would be reasonable to use only one of them, and using both could be redundant... But I still have doubts whether if I omit one, not all error types could be handled. Or is it really redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `poolConnection` over normal connections.
I am using a MVC based architecture with `mysql2` and  `nodejs-express`.

Here's how you can create the `connector.js` file for establishing database connections.

```
// connector.js

const mysql = require('mysql2');
var connection = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    // port: 3306,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    multipleStatements: true
});
connection.getConnection((err) => {
    if (err) console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    else {
        console.log('Connected!')
    }
});
module.exports = connection.promise();
```

And to execute a query use this method over `con.query`

```
const con = require('../database/connector.js');

const fn = async ( params ) => {
  try{
     const [data] = await con.execute('select * from tbl_users where user = ?',[params]);
     return data;
  } catch(err) {
     return false;
  }
}
```